# Foursquare Campaign Timeseries viewingUsers and unlockingUsers always returns 0

Tags: foursquare

Why is Foursquare Campaign Timeseries viewingUsers and unlockingUsers always returning 0? Thanks. I tried with a simple check-in special and was able to unlock it already and asked a number of friends to view it and check in as well but no luck. Thanks!

Comment: What's the venue / campaign ID that you're seeing this issue for?

Comment: And can you post the request you're making to foursquare's servers? (minus your oauth token)

Comment: https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore#req=campaigns/4fe2f484c2eecd9a180fbbda/timeseries I'm viewing results from web using "try it now" button from foursquare api campaign timeseries endpoint. Thanks!

Comment: Just to clarify akdotcom. a user checked in yesterday from mobile and viewed and unlocked yesterday. although it seems the count is reflected today. is this the expected behavior? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the viewing/unlocking Users stats are updated in realtime just yet, so as long as the data shows up after a day or two, that's the expected behavior. You may want to also try specifying startAt and endAt as part of the request if you care about a particular time range.

Comment: thank you very much. If I may ask, too, what if I have a campaign that runs forever (no specified start and end date or at least for 6mo to a year), may I know the limit of array return for each parameter given that I don't specify the date range? (ex: campaign running for 1 year is 365 array of data for viewingUsers) Thanks!

Comment: Even if you don't specify a start time, there's a coherent start time in our database and that will be used as the beginning of the default window of statistics.

Comment: May I know what is the maximum number of array content to be returned for each metric (total checkins, new checkins, viewing users, unlocking users)? Especially for campaigns that are running for a year. Thanks